# How to integrate Google business messaging through API

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Problems:

1. I am unable to enable Business Messages API, Because **"Business Messages API"** is not showing  API list, While i am going to enable the API through the

   https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard
2. I want to use auth token, while hitting the API, but the document  is saying use the service.json for the credentials. i am following these doc. I am using **"Google\Client()"** with Laravel application.

   https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides/how-to/agents?method=api

I am following these steps:

Login with google business account in the Dashboard
App taking multiple permissions as [I have attached the permissions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiFIb.png) and taking the auth token.

2. Open the chat box for the Business.

So please guide me, where i am going wrong. What is correct way to implement this.

**Requirement**:

I want to create a custom chat box for google businesses, Where business owner will login into the web app and He can easily manage the multiple business chats in one dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

As per your given information, you have to be a partner of Google. As per google documentation, you need to be a partner of google and then you can create the agent and can send and receive messages. You can integrate the business messages API by following this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/business-communications/business-messages/guides

In this process, you need to be a partner of Google. The complete process is given on the link. If you follow this link, then you can use their built-in libraries easily and can send messages easily.

So far the permission for API, it might not be found for you because you might have to take permission for the particular project that is registered on google and then you will see the business messages API and you can enable it and use it. The reason as per the basic step:

https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup

Sometimes, you have to submit the request form to take the API access for particular APIs. Or Share how are you using that API.

If you do not find a form for business messages API then you can ask for the information from bm-support@google.com. they mostly respond on a working day.